# Definition of Fourier coefficients in PMA Rudin

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-series

W.Rudin in his book "Principles of MA" defines Fourier coefficients by $(62)$ i.e. $$c_m=\dfrac{1}{2\pi}\int _{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)e^{-imx}dx \qquad (62)$$ But in **8.10 Definiton**  for orthonormal system $\{\phi_n(x)\}$ on $[a,b]$ he defines Fourier coefficients by $(66)$ i.e. $$c_n=\int _{a}^{b}f(t)\overline{\phi_n(t)}dt \qquad (66)$$ But we know that system $\left\{\dfrac{e^{inx}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\right\}_{n\in \mathbb{Z}}$ is orthonormal on $[-\pi,\pi]$ and putting this into $(66)$ we get that $c_n=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int \limits_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(t)e^{-int}dt$ and this does not coincide with $(62)$

Can anyone explain this confusing moment please?

Comment: I strongly suspect that he uses the normalised Haar measure on the unit circle, which is Lebesgue measure divided by $2\pi$.

Comment: A Fourier series on $[-\pi,\pi]$ is $\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}c_n e^{inx}$. No matter how you define things, either by changing inner products or renormalizing the functions, the associated series for $f \in L^2[-\pi,\pi]$ is $\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}c_n e^{inx}$ with $c_n = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(t)e^{-int}dt$. The classical definition is that the $c_n$'s are the Fourier coefficients.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He, too, appears to be confused by the mutually incompatible definitions in the literature. Interestingly, in chapter 7 of his book "Functional Analysis" he solves the problem by redefining Lebesgue measure. The *normalized Lebesgue measure* on $\mathbb R^n$ is the measure $m_n$ defined by

$$dm_n(x)=(2\pi)^{-n/2}dx.$$

Comment: +1. Interesting remark! May I ask you question? But if $\{\phi_n(x)\}$ is orthonormal system how Fourier series $c_n$ defined in this case?

Comment: For example $\phi_n(x)=\frac{e^{inx}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$

Comment: As soon as you even mention the word orthonormal it should be (66). The other convention (62) dates back to more innocent times when the integrals were written separately for the sine and the cosine; its only saving grace was easier typography in the pre-LaTeX era.

Comment: So Rudin made mistake or not?

Comment: But the only problem that worries me it's that $(62)$ does not coincide with $(66)$

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, he's employing two different conventions.  Notice that in $(63)$ he writes $$\sum c_{n} e^{inx}$$ so he's thinking of $\{e^{inx}\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ as his orthonormal basis, not $\{\frac{e^{inx}}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$.  Of course, you could multiply and divide by $\sqrt{2 \pi}$ to get $$\sum a_{n} \frac{e^{inx}}{\sqrt{2 \pi}},$$ where $a_{n}$ satisfies the formula you were expecting $$a_{n} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_{- \pi}^{\pi} f(t) e^{-int} \, dt.$$

Ultimately, it's a question of what exactly you mean by orthonormality.  I don't know if you know what an inner product space is, but I'll put it this way.  If you define an orthonormal basis $\{\phi_{n}\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ by requiring $$\int_{a}^{b} \phi_{n}(x) \overline{\phi_{m}(x)} \, dx = \left \{ \begin{array}{c c} 1, & n = m \\ 0, & \text{otherwise} \end{array} \right.$$ then $$\left \{\frac{e^{inx}}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \right\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$$ is the right choice as far as Fourier series are concerned.  On the other hand, you can also define an orthornormal basis $\{\phi_{n}\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ using the formula $$\frac{1}{b - a} \int_{a}^{b} \phi_{n}(x) \overline{\phi_{m}(x)} \, dx = \left \{ \begin{array}{c c} 1, & n = m \\ 0, & \text{otherwise} \end{array} \right.$$  There are a number of reasons this is a nice alternative.  In our case, it's nice that $\{e^{inx}\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is now orthornormal so we needn't keep track of factors of $\sqrt{2 \pi}$.

Comment: In (63) he does not consider $\{e^{inx}\}$ as orthonormal system as you said.

Comment: But his (66) does not coincide with (62). That's a problem

Comment: For what it's worth, the discussion around (63) precedes the definition of orthonormal system.  However, if you look, for example, at Rudin's _Real and Complex Analysis_ you will see the orthonormal system used to study Fourier series in that book is, in fact, $\{e^{inx}\}$.